# didBeginContact Freezes

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am generating a random number and accessing an array of colors to set a sprite's color on contact. But it freezes the first time didBeginContact() is called. My code looks like this:

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    index = Int (arc4random_uniform(5))

    ball.fillColor = col[index]
```

Where `col` is an array of `UIColor` and `ball` is an `SKShapeNode`. It works fine after the first collision but the first collision freezes the game. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this all the code that is running? Are you completely sure that this makes lag?

Comment: does it generate an error? if it freezes how do you get to the second collision?